# Extracting maximum values from each of the subsets of an array

Tags: python, array, numpy, vectorization

**Problem description:**

I have a numpy array `cps` from which I want to extract the maximum value in each of the
subsets of the array (a subset is defined as non-zero values which fall between zeros). The input and how the output should look like are illustrated in the following figure.

**Note:** `cps` only contains positive values and zeros.

[image: The input and the desired output]

for the moment, I am doing this as below:

```
## cps is a numpy array which contains values as observed in the figure

idx = np.nonzero(cps)
subsets = np.array_split(idx[0],np.where(np.diff(idx[0])!=1)[0]+1)  
lst = np.full(len(cps), 0) 

for subset in subsets:
    min = subset[0]   ## index of the start of subset (the smallest index number)
    max = subset[-1]  ## index of the end of subset (the largest index number)

    index_of_change_point_with_max_value = min + np.argmax(cps[min:max+1])        

    lst[index_of_change_point_with_max_value] = cps[index_of_change_point_with_max_value]
```

However, I was wondering if there is anyway to do this in a vectorized manner and getting
rid of the for loop?

Comment: Can't get your code to work in Python; it's missing a bracket on the line that initializes `subsets` and there's no `full` function in `numpy`, apparently.

Comment: please check your version of Numpy. `np.full()` is available in version 1.8 and above. I am using version 1.8.1. Also, I checked the syntax; it should work! There is no missing brackets! (Works just fine on my system!)

Comment: My mistake, probably accidentally deleted some character. Also, got your code working. It's a bit late to ask this question now, but what is your input size?

Comment: The input size varies. However, on average, there are around 200,000 datapoints in the `cps` array.

Comment: Ahh. For that input size performance won't matter much. Anyways, you have already found a solution that fits your needs elegantly; feel free to accept your own answer. :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have to do this 24 times(considering that there are 24 chromosomes in human genome: 22 autosomes plus x and y chromosomes)!

Comment: Your solution will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a neat way to do the trick by using the [argrelmax()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmax.html#scipy.signal.argrelmax) function from `scipy.signal` module. It seems that it does not increase the performance in my code, however, the code becomes more readable.

**The solution:**

```
import scipy.signal as sig
lst = np.full(len(cps), 0)    
indices = sig.argrelmax(cps)
lst[indices] = cps[indices]
```

Comment: May not work for subarrays that contain *only* negative numbers, as 0 is greater than negative numbers.

Comment: True. But luckily, the `cps`array in my case only contains positive values!

Comment: Ahh, next time pls state that in your question. :) The subset being defined as "non-zero values that fall between zeros" was misleading.

Comment: Sure! I was thinking that it was obvious from the illustration!

Answer (score 1):

## Single pass algorithm (~2n)

You can do it with a single pass over the array (which I shall denote as `lst`).

1. Maintain a maximum value (I shall denote this as `max_val`) once you hit a non-zero value. When we reach a zero, add `(i, max_val)` to the list of maximum values and reset the maximum value.
2. Build the new list using the list of maximum values.

This should give you pretty good performance (~2n since you iterate 2 times). However, if you need a parallel version...

## Parallel algorithm

This is the first parallel algorithm I've ever designed, so pardon me if I screwed up somewhere. We use the [MapReduce model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) which is quite simple to write.

Let `k` be the number of processes which you want to divide the work among and `i` be the number of each process where `0 <= i < k`.

In the `Map()` procedure:

1. Each process starts at `n/k * i` indice and iterates till it hits `n/k * (i+1)`.
2. Follow the algorithm as described in step 1 of the single pass algorithm.
3. If the first or last value is non-zero, it indicates that the values we have obtained may not be the maximum values of the subset as we may have only monitored a portion of the subset. Hence, we add it to the portions list.

When we flush, we mark the start and end indice that we have scanned and the maximum value, so as to indicate that we have not finished scanning that subarray.

For `k = 3` and our array being `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1] + [2, 3, 4, 0, 0] + [0, 2, 1, 0, 2]` with a length of 15 (split into 3 segments for convenience):

```
i = 0: lst[0] = 0
       lst[1] = 0
       lst[2] = 0
       lst[3] = 0
       lst[4] = 1 # is_portion = True, max_val = 1
                  # add (4, 5, (4, 1)) to the list of portions
       return [] and [(4, 5, (4, 1))]
i = 1: lst[5] = 2 # is_portion = True, max_val = 2
       lst[6] = 3 # max_val = 3
       lst[7] = 4 # max_val = 4
       lst[8] = 0 # add (5, 8, (8, 4)) to the list of portions
       lst[9] = 0
       return [] and [(5, 8, (8, 4))]
i = 2: lst[10] = 0
       lst[11] = 2 # max_val = 2
       lst[12] = 1
       lst[13] = 0 # add (11, 2) to the list of maximum values
       lst[14] = 2 # is_portion = True, max_val = 2
                   # add (14, 15, (14, 2)) to the list of portions
       return [(11, 2)] and [(14, 15, (14, 2))]
```

In the `Reduce()` procedure, we merge the arrays we have together to form two lists:

```
1. Maximum values: [(11, 2)]
2. Portions not yet finished scanning: [(4, 5, (4, 1)), (5, 8, (8, 4)), (14, 15, (14, 2))]
  We merge the tuples (4, 5, (4, 1)) and (5, 8, (8, 4)) together and compare the maximum value found. (8, 4) > (4, 1), so we get a maximum value (8, 4).
  The last tuple, (14, 15, (14, 2)), ends at the boundary of the array, so we immediately return the maximum value (14, 2).
```

We now get `[(11, 2), (8, 4), (14, 2)]`. We build the list using step 2 and we're done!

The time complexity should be around ~2n if you choose a good `k` value.

Comment: I am going to implement your first idea and do some benchmarking and see which one is faster. I was considering it even before but I was ruling it out since I was thinking it is implemented by a for loop, it would never be any faster!

Comment: @Dataman My guess is that your code will be less performant as it involves the copying of data and has the same (or greater) time complexity. I may be mistaken, though.